# Sort out terms linear in a certain function

Tags: symbolic

Considering the following term

```
(I*gm*knlt*om*Integrate[(dx10[om1] + x10bar[om1] - x20[om1])*(dx10[om - om1 - om2] + x10bar[om - om1 - om2] - x20[om - om1 - om2])*(dx10[om2] + x10bar[om2] - x20[om2]), {om1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   {om2, -Infinity, Infinity}])/(-(kext*kl) - I*gm*kext*om - (2*I)*gm*kl*om + gm^2*om^2)
```

I want to collect/keep only terms linear in the function `x10bar` (no matter of which argument). How would you do this in a swift way with Mathematica? I was trying to apply series expansion (which is difficult with functions) or pattern matching but failed so far.

Any help is highly appreciated!

[Edit]

The expected output should be

```
(I*gm*knlt*om*Integrate[dx10[om - om1 - om2]*dx10[om2]*x10bar[om1] + dx10[om1]*dx10[om2]*x10bar[om - om1 - om2] + dx10[om1]*dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om2] - dx10[om2]*x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1] - 
    dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om2]*x20[om1] - dx10[om2]*x10bar[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - dx10[om1]*x10bar[om2]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - x10bar[om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - 
    dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om1]*x20[om2] - dx10[om1]*x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] + x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om2] + x10bar[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2], {om1, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   {om2, -Infinity, Infinity}])/(-(kext*kl) - I*gm*kext*om - (2*I)*gm*kl*om + gm^2*om^2)
```

Comment: It would clarify what you want if you edit your question to show the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

#### Internal`LinearQ

```
{#, Internal`LinearQ[#, {x, y, z}]} & /@ 
  {1, x, y, a b c z, x + y + 3 z, a x^2 + y + z, x y z}
```

> {{1, False},
>   {x, True},
>   {y, True},
>    {a b c z, True},
>    {x + y + 3 z, True},
>    {a x^2 + y + z, False},
>   {x y z, False}}

Taking only the integrand of the expression in OP and applying `LinearQ`:

```
integrand0 = Cases[expr0, Integrate[a_, b__] :> a][[1]]
```

> (dx10[om1] + x10bar[om1] - x20[om1]) (dx10[om - om1 - om2] + 
>          x10bar[om - om1 - om2] - x20[om - om1 - om2]) (dx10[om2] + 
>          x10bar[om2] - x20[om2])

```
vars = Cases[integrand0, x10bar[__], Infinity]
```

> {x10bar[om1], x10bar[om - om1 - om2], x10bar[om2]}

```
integrand1 = Select[ExpandAll[integrand0],  Internal`LinearQ[#, vars] &]
```

> dx10[om - om1 - om2] dx10[om2] x10bar[om1] +
>    dx10[om1] dx10[om2] x10bar[om - om1 - om2] +
>    dx10[om1] dx10[om - om1 - om2] x10bar[om2] -
>    dx10[om2] x10bar[om - om1 - om2] x20[om1] -
>    dx10[om - om1 - om2] x10bar[om2] x20[om1] -
>    dx10[om2] x10bar[om1] x20[om - om1 - om2] -
>    dx10[om1] x10bar[om2] x20[om - om1 - om2] +
>    x10bar[om2] x20[om1] x20[om - om1 - om2] -
>    dx10[om - om1 - om2] x10bar[om1] x20[om2] -
>    dx10[om1] x10bar[om - om1 - om2] x20[om2] +
>    x10bar[om - om1 - om2] x20[om1] x20[om2] +
>    x10bar[om1] x20[om - om1 - om2] x20[om2]

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = (I*gm*knlt*om*
     Integrate[(dx10[om1] + x10bar[om1] - 
         x20[om1])*(dx10[om - om1 - om2] + x10bar[om - om1 - om2] - 
         x20[om - om1 - om2])*(dx10[om2] + x10bar[om2] - 
         x20[om2]), {om1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {om2, -Infinity, 
       Infinity}])/(-(kext*kl) - I*gm*kext*om - (2*I)*gm*kl*om + 
     gm^2*om^2);
```

Use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) on [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) to be able to [`ExpandAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpandAll.html) its argument

```
expr2 = (expr /. Integrate -> Inactive[Integrate] // ExpandAll) /. 
   a_.*x10bar[__]*x10bar[_]*b_ :> 0 // Activate

(* (I*gm*knlt*om*Integrate[dx10[om1]*dx10[om - om1 - om2]*
            dx10[om2] + dx10[om - om1 - om2]*dx10[om2]*
            x10bar[om1] + dx10[om1]*dx10[om2]*
            x10bar[om - om1 - om2] + dx10[om1]*
            dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om2] - 
          dx10[om - om1 - om2]*dx10[om2]*x20[om1] - 
          dx10[om2]*x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1] - 
          dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om2]*x20[om1] - 
          dx10[om1]*dx10[om2]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - 
          dx10[om2]*x10bar[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - 
          dx10[om1]*x10bar[om2]*x20[om - om1 - om2] + 
          dx10[om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] + 
          x10bar[om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] - 
          dx10[om1]*dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] - 
          dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x10bar[om1]*x20[om2] - 
          dx10[om1]*x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] + 
          dx10[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om2] + 
          x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om2] + 
          dx10[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] + 
          x10bar[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] - 
          x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2], 
        {om1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {om2, -Infinity, Infinity}])/
   ((-kext)*kl - I*gm*kext*om - 2*I*gm*kl*om + gm^2*om^2) *)

expr2 // FullSimplify

(* (I*gm*knlt*om*Integrate[(-dx10[om2])*x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*
            x20[om1] - dx10[om2]*x10bar[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] + 
          dx10[om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] + 
          x10bar[om2]*x20[om1]*x20[om - om1 - om2] + 
          (x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om1] + 
               (x10bar[om1] - x20[om1])*x20[om - om1 - om2])*
            x20[om2] + dx10[om - om1 - om2]*
            (dx10[om2]*(x10bar[om1] - x20[om1]) - 
               x10bar[om2]*x20[om1] + (-x10bar[om1] + x20[om1])*
                 x20[om2]) + dx10[om1]*
            (dx10[om2]*(x10bar[om - om1 - om2] - 
                    x20[om - om1 - om2]) + dx10[om - om1 - om2]*
                 (dx10[om2] + x10bar[om2] - x20[om2]) - 
               x10bar[om - om1 - om2]*x20[om2] + x20[om - om1 - om2]*
                 (-x10bar[om2] + x20[om2])), {om1, -Infinity, 
          Infinity}, {om2, -Infinity, Infinity}])/
   ((-kext)*kl - I*gm*(kext + 2*kl)*om + gm^2*om^2) *)
```